# Angular HTTP promise returns empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory with a HTTP GET request and I used promises as the documentations says I should, using $q service, but it is returning an empty promise:

```
App.factory('dataFactory', ['$rootScope','$http','$q', function($rootScope,$http,$q) {

  // Objeto del factory 
  var fac = {};

  // Funcion que obtiene un mensaje completo
  fac.obtenerListaMensajes = function(compania,userhid){

    var deferred = $q.defer(); 

    $http({ 
            method: 'GET', 
            url: urlListaMensajes, 
            params: {company:compania,userhid:userhid}
          }).
      then(function(response) {

        deferred.resolve(response.data.messages);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(deferred.promise));

        }, function(error) {
          deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return fac;

}]);
```

The controller:

```
App.controller('MailFolderController', ['$scope','$rootScope','dataFactory', '$stateParams', function($scope, $rootScope, dataFactory, $stateParams) {

  // Variables de PRUEBA
  var user_prueba = 'MTQzMjU4NjUyNDcxMzczNzQwNjE3MTg1ODMxMDY5OTQ2';
  var company_prueba = 'development';

  $scope.mails = dataFactory.obtenerListaMensajes(company_prueba,user_prueba);
}]);
```

The final value in $scope.mails is:

```
{"$$state":{"status":0}}
```

I know for a fact that the HTTP request works properly thanks to the console.log inside it.

What am I doing wrong? I could use $rootScope to return the value, it works, but it would be a bad programming strategy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper way to use service in controller would be:

```
dataFactory.obtenerListaMensajes(company_prueba, user_prueba).then(function(data) {
    $scope.mails = data;
});
```

Also you can improve service by getting rid of redundant dummy deferred object, you don't need it since `$http` already returns promise:

```
App.factory('dataFactory', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {

    // Objeto del factory 
    var fac = {};

    // Funcion que obtiene un mensaje completo
    fac.obtenerListaMensajes = function (compania, userhid) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: urlListaMensajes,
            params: {
                company: compania,
                userhid: userhid
            }
        }).
        then(function (response) {
            return response.data.messages;
        });
    };

    return fac;

}]);
```

Comment: So it was just ignorance from my part. Thank you.